# Crystal Reports suppress 0 in Pie Chart

Tags: crystal-reports, pie-chart

Thanks in advance for any help,

I have a Crystal Report made in Crystal Reports 2011. The report does a simple select from a view and uses about 6 of the columns.

In 2 consecutive sections there is a Cross Tab and a Pie chart, both reporting on the same formula field. The formula for the field is as follows:

```
  iif( IsNull({IROView.OVERTURNREASON})=false, {OVERTURNREASON},"")
```

Basically, if my value is not null, I get the value, and if it is, I get an empty string.

In the Cross Tab, under the Customize Style tab, there is a Suppress Empty Rows and Suppress Empty Columns check box. I am looking for something similar for the pie chart because even though there is no slice for the empty string, the legend has a an entry for the blank string with the value 0 (or 0%).

Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider updating the charting engine to use the latest version of [CRChart](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/product_info.php).  Three-D Graphics wrote the original component for SAP (nee BusinessObjects nee Crystal Decisions nee Seagate Software); they own the source code.  The [@HIDE_ZERO](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/html_docs/docs/macros/hide_zero.htm) macro would probably do exactly what you need to have done.

Comment: That looks nice, but I'm not interested in purchasing more software to resolve this issue.